# Could not load assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json' using ml.net in Azure Web Api

Tags: ml.net, azure-webapps

**TL;DR**

In an Azure-hosted Web API, an ML.net model fails to load due to a missing Newtonsoft.Json dependency.

---

**Details**

I've a C# `net6.0` Azure hosted Web API that loads and calls a pre-built ML.net (v1.7.0) model (multi-classification using `SdcaMaximumEntropy`, in case that's relevant).

I've tested it locally using a console app to call the `localhost` web api. This is then deployed, via a GitHub action, to an Azure Api App (action yaml snippet below).

```yaml
      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: '6.0.x'
          include-prerelease: true
```

Once deployed, I can call the relevant endpoint but an exception is generated from the `Model.Load` method below. [The api returns a 500 ... the detail is available via Azure App Insights.]

```cs
private readonly MLContext _mlContext;
...
var loadedModel = _mlContext.Model.Load(_modelPath, out var _);
```

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Any pointers as to why that's happening gratefully received; let me know if there's any further info required.

---

**Further Info**

1. In the project, `Newtonsoft.Json` is only required/referenced by the `Microsoft.ML` package.
2. I've checked in the Advanced Tools (kudu) to ensure `NewtonSoft.Json` is being deployed.
3. I've tried adding an explicit reference to the `Newtonsoft.Json` package; I've also tried adding another package that has a reference to Newtonsoft; I've switched the `Model.Load` to the more robust `AddPredictionEnginePool` variation. None of these had any impact (but still work locally).
4. I've checked that the `_modelPath` of the model was being set to the right location [`D:\home\site\wwwroot\SupporterCategoriser\Data\model.zip`], and that the model exists, in case the missing model was somehow being mis-reported.
5. n.b. There have been numerous Newtonsoft `FileNotFoundException` questions posted over the last decade, none seemed to be related.
6. n.b. There are also [plans to remove the Newtonsoft dependency from the ML package](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/4359) but not for any related reason.

---

Stack trace

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute._CreateCaObject (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.CreateCaObject (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.AddCustomAttributes (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetCustomAttributes (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.ML.Runtime.ComponentCatalog.RegisterAssembly (Microsoft.ML.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.EnsureLoaderAssemblyIsRegistered (Microsoft.ML.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModelCore (Microsoft.ML.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.TryLoadModel (Microsoft.ML.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel (Microsoft.ML.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModelOrNull (Microsoft.ML.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelLoadContext.LoadModel (Microsoft.ML.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.Load (Microsoft.ML.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at Microsoft.ML.ModelOperationsCatalog.Load (Microsoft.ML.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51)
   at GolfGuruApi.SupporterCategoriser.Services.CategoryService.PredictIssue (XxxApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\xxx-api\xxx-api\XxxApi\SupporterCategoriser\Services\CategoryService.cs:143)
   at XxxApi.SupporterCategoriser.Services.CategoryService.GetCategory (XxxApi, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\xxx-api\xxx-api\XxxApi\SupporterCategoriser\Services\CategoryService.cs:31)
   at lambda_method2 (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory+<>c__DisplayClass46_3+<<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegate>b__2>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware+<<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0>d.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1+<ProcessRequestAsync>d__2.MoveNext (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
```

---

`csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML" Version="1.7.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="SupporterCategoriser\Data\model.zip">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please share your .csproj file ? There might be mismatch in the packages version.

Comment: csproj added, thanks.

Comment: Add  ***Newtonsoft.Json***   <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" /> in .csproj and check once

Comment: hi, yes, I'd already tried that (see note#3 above -- apologies, there's a lot of detail to wade through). Next step: I'm going to publish directly rather than via GitHub.

Comment: Also possibly relevant: I'm deploying to the Free App Service Plan (F1), so am restricted to 32 bit on that. I've not specified target architecture anywhere, so this may be a red herring, but may try to see if forcing to x86 helps.

Comment: I have the same exact problem with ML.NET version 2.0.0. ...